# Simulate animation inside custom view on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-animation, android-custom-view

I have a custom view which looks like a spinning wheel with numbers from 0 to 9.
Basically it scrolls down from 0 to 9 while I am downloading something from the server and when the value is returned, the animation stops on it. The animation is made by updating the Y value of the text I am drawing

Some relevant code:

```
public class TimeSpinner extends View
{

    .....
    private void initialize()
    {
    .....

        handler = new Handler();
        repetitiveRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateData();
            }
        };

    }

    public void updateData() {

        float delta = 3;

        mDigitY += delta;
        mDigitAboveY += delta;
        mDigitBelowY += delta;

        //Test if animation needs to stop
        if (mCurrentDigit == animateToDigit) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(repetitiveRunnable);
        } else {
            handler.postDelayed(repetitiveRunnable, 5);
        }

        invalidate();
    }


    public void startLoadingDigit() {
        handler.postDelayed(repetitiveRunnable, 5);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawText(mDigitString, mDigitX, mDigitY, mDigitPaint);
        canvas.drawText(mDigitAboveString, mDigitX, mDigitAboveY, mDigitPaint);
        canvas.drawText(mDigitBelowString, mDigitX, mDigitBelowY, mDigitPaint);

    }

}
```

The problem is the UI thread has some drawing to do on the other views so depending on phone's speed the animation is not fluid. Is like having bad frame rate or sometimes it stops for half of second. On powerful devices is reasonable good.

Now the question, what can I do make the animation smooth independent of what the app is doing ? The View is simple, not a SurfaceView. Should I use a thread somehow ? A code sample would be great.

Later edit.

I tried using an AsycTask for updating the Y coordinate

```
public class TimeSpinnerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

            while (animationRunning) {

                updateData();
                publishProgress();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(35);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            invalidate();
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            invalidate();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

public void updateData() {

        mDigitY += delta;
        mDigitAboveY += delta;
        mDigitBelowY += delta;

        if (mDigitAboveY > findCenterY(mCurrentDigit)) {
            setCurrentDigit(mDigitAbove);
        }

        if (mCurrentDigit == animateToDigit) {

            animationRunning = false;

            setCurrentDigit(animateToDigit);
        }
    }
```

While this does seem to be a bit smoother, on older devices I still get shutter, sometimes the animation even pauses for 1 seconds before continuing.

The asynctask is started with `executeOnExecutor` and the view is shown over a Map control from Android Maps V2. The shuttering appears especially when the map is loading tiles.

Maybe I didn't go with the best approach. Here is the final result I want to obtain:
[image]
Any ideas ?

Comment: you postDelayed with 5ms? it means 200 fps, why?

Comment: Each postDelayed adds 3 to Y coordinate... At 5ms I got a reasonable speed. This probably has to do with not using a separate thread...

Comment: then use a custom Animation, override applyTransformation and change Y coordinate based on its interpolatedTime

Comment: @pskink I dont think is that easy. Since I am animating I need to have 2 numbers on the screen, when the scroll happens and I am not sure I can implement this using an animation.

Comment: one is placed in Y and the second Y + SOMECONSTANTOFFSET? right?

Comment: Yes, but the animation needs to be inside the customview since I am tracking the numbers and animation to returned value

Comment: i dont understand, in applyTransformation do nothig, just Log.d intrrpolatedTime, then everything will be obvious

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried using a [`ValueAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html)? This is designed for managing animations similar to yours. It will take care of the threading and framerate for you.

```
// Create a new value animator that will use the range 0 to 1
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);

// It will take 5000ms for the animator to go from 0 to 1
animator.setDuration(5000);

// Callback that executes on animation steps. 
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue())).floatValue();

        Log.d("ValueAnimator", "value=" + value);

        // Here you can now translate or redraw your view
        // You need to map 'value' to your animation in regards to time
        // eg) mDigitY = value; invalidate();
    }
});
```

You can also probably achieve that elastic effect at the end of the animation by using an [`OvershootInterpolator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/OvershootInterpolator.html).

```
animator.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
```

Comment: Interesting, so I can use this animator inside my custom view ? I will take a look at it

Comment: I've update the code to better explain what needs to be done. Some reworking to your current algorithim will need to take place. for example, you can remove the concept of 'delta'

Comment: `addUpdateListener` is a method of `ValueAnimator`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have other AsyncTasks running at the same time, you can try starting AsyncTask on separate thread with `task.executeOnExecutor` to decouple from them. But the drawing will still be done on the main thread.

I would suggest searching for other things that can block the UI thread or big memory allocations causing the garbage collector to be started. Look for `GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 190K, 13% free 5409K/6164K, paused 67ms, total 71ms` in your logcat.

Also, drawText is relatively expensive operation. You can cache the result of font drawing and draw it from the bitmap.

But if the map is blocking the UI thread there is not much you can do about that without using OpenGL directly.

Comment: The asynctask is started with `executeOnExecutor` and the view is shown over a Map control from Android Maps V2. The shuttering appears especially when the map is loading tiles.

Comment: I added one more thing you can try :)

Answer (score 0):

How about having these images in drawable folder of the application. Then you can have an animation folder hold a XML file that defines the transition of images from 0 to 9. Set this animation to an imageView. Finally, when you do have a number returned from the web-service, reset the imageView's associated image to the one corrosponding to the number.

**Animation XML(number_slider.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/num_0"
        android:duration="150"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/num_1"
        android:duration="150"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/num_2"
        android:duration="150"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/num_3"
        android:duration="150"/>
</animation-list>
```

**Code:**
a) Start Animation

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.number_slider);
AnimationDrawable  loadingViewAnim = (AnimationDrawable) thumbnail.getBackground();
loadingViewAnim.start();
```

b) Stop Animation and set the number returned from web-service to image view

```
loadingViewAnim.stop();
imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.num_3));
```

Finally you can define various effects in the number_slider.xml file to make the animation more "animated". You can introduce the "bounce effect", "Speed-Control", any thing that you can imagine of. Moreover no serialization is required and I assume this approach will make the animations smoother across all device configurations.